# Is there a way to capture a subroutine's print output to a variable so I can send it to stderr instead?

Tags: perl, stderr

Suppose we have:

```
sub test {
        print "testing\n";
}
```

If there is a case where I want to have it print to stderr instead of stdout, is there a way I can call the subroutine to do this? Or can I capture the output to a variable and then use warn? I'm fairly new to perl.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes there is. `print` sends its output to the "selected" filehandle, which is usually `STDOUT`. But Perl provides the [`select`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlfunc#select) function for you to change it.

```
select(STDERR);
&test;           # send output to STDERR
select(STDOUT);  # restore default output handle
```

The `select` function returns the previously selected filehandle, so you can capture it and restore it later.

```
my $orig_select = select(STDERR);
&test;
select($orig_select);
```

Comment: +1  Note that a fatal exception in test() will leave a nonstandard FILEHANDLE select()d, which is why I local()ize in my answer below.

Answer (score 9):

Perl's dynamic scoping via [local()](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/local.html) is not often used, but this strikes me as a good application for it:

```
test(); # to stdout
{
    open(local *STDOUT, ">&STDERR") or die "dup out to err: $!";
    test(); # to stderr, locally calling it "STDOUT"
}
test(); # to stdout again
```

The call to `test()` in the block above -- as well as to anything that `test()` itself might call -- will have STDOUT dynamically scoped to your duplicate of STDERR.  When control leaves the block, even if by `die()`ing, STDOUT will be restored to whatever it was before the block

Generalized:

```
sub out2err(&) {
  my $user_block = shift;
  open(local *STDOUT, ">&STDERR") or die $!;
  $user_block->();
}

test();             # to stdout
out2err { test() }; # to stderr
test();             # to stdout
```

Comment: +1 This will work even if the given function prints to `STDOUT` explicitly.

Answer (score 3):

Meanwhile, you can also "capture a subroutine's print output to a variable."

Just pass a scalar ref to `open`:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
use common::sense;
use autodie;

sub tostring (&) {
  my $s;
  open local *STDOUT, '>', \$s;
  shift->();
  $s
}

sub fake {
  say 'lalala';
  say 'more stuff';
  say 1 + 1, ' = 2';
  say for @_;
}

for (tostring { fake(1, 2, 3) }) {
  s/\n/\\n/g;
  say "Captured as string: >>>$_<<<";
}
```

Output:

```
Captured as string: >>>lalala\nmore stuff\n2 = 2\n1\n2\n3\n<<<
```

Answer (score 1):

This work for me

```
local *STDOUT;
open(STDOUT, ">", \$Result);
&test();
print $Result;
```

Comment: This code will not work and will print nothing instead of the result printed by &test();. The following code will work:
`do
{
 local *STDOUT;
 open(STDOUT, ">", \$Result);
 &test();
};
print $Result;`