# extracting html between tags using perl

Tags: html, perl, html-parsing

I want to extract all the html between the  tag of a string or file Ive been looking at using (perl) with the module html::parser, I thought this would be a simple task but its turning out to be quite tricky?  I found some code which works but dont know how to save results to a string ??   any help appreciated
or if you can show me some code on how this can be achived using HTML::TokeParser or similar.

Thanks

```
my $content=<<EOF;
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
   <title>Some title goes here</title>
 </head>
 <body bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
   <div id="leftcol">
     menu column
  </div>
  <div id="body">
   <p>some text goes here some text goes here<br />
    some text goes here some text goes here</p>
   <p><strong>some header</strong></p>
   <p>some text goes here some text goes here<br />
   some text goes here some text goes here</p>
    <p><img src="img.gif" /> image here</p>
   <p><strong>some header</strong></p>
   <p>some text goes here some text goes here<br />
   some text goes here some text goes here</p>
   </div>
    <div id="rightcol">
   news column
    </div>
 </body>
</html>
EOF


my $p = HTML::Parser->new( api_version => 3 );
$p->handler( start => \&start_handler, "self,tagname,attr" );
$p->parse($content);
exit;

sub start_handler {
    my $self = shift;
    my $tagname  = shift;
    my $attr = shift;
    my $text = shift;
    return unless ( $tagname eq 'body' );
    $self->handler( start => sub { print shift }, "text" );
    $self->handler( text =>  sub { print shift }, "text" );
    $self->handler( end  => sub {
    my ($endtagname, $self, $text) = @_;
         if($endtagname eq $tagname) {
         $self->eof;
         } else {
              print $text;
        }
    }, "tagname,self,text");
 }
```

---

if i modify the above Sub routine start text and end handlers like below

### why doesnt the text from those varibles get saved in mine ?

```
$self->handler( start => sub {  my ($text) = @_; $inner_body = $inner_body. $text; }, "text" );
$self->handler( text =>  sub {  my ($text) = @_; $inner_body = $inner_body. $text; }, "text" );
$self->handler( end  => sub {
       my ($endtagname, $self, $text) = @_;
       if($endtagname eq $tagname) {
            $self->eof;
           } else {
             $inner_body = $inner_body. $text;
           }
        }, "tagname,self,text");
```

}

### print $inner_body;  # <-- prints blank ???

Desired output to be saved in varible

---

```
   <div id="leftcol">
     menu column
  </div>
  <div id="body">
   <p>some text goes here some text goes here<br />
    some text goes here some text goes here</p>
   <p><strong>some header</strong></p>
   <p>some text goes here some text goes here<br />
   some text goes here some text goes here</p>
    <p><img src="img.gif" /> image here</p>
   <p><strong>some header</strong></p>
   <p>some text goes here some text goes here<br />
   some text goes here some text goes here</p>
   </div>
    <div id="rightcol">
   news column
    </div>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16615269/is-there-a-way-to-capture-a-subroutines-print-output-to-a-variable-so-i-can-sen/16620184#16620184

Comment: Re your update: How can you claim that `exit(0); print $inner_body;` prints blank?

Comment: cause it does ? why is there something im missing when i print $inner_body  i get the following   [root@nurelay ~]# ./parsetest
[root@nurelay ~]#

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is replace

```
print ...;
```

with

```
$inner_body .= ...;
```

---

Personally, I would use XML::LibXML instead. It can handle both HTML and XML (by using the appropriate method of the parser). What you have there is XHTML (which is XML-compatible), so we use `parse_string` instead of `parse_html_string`.

```
use XML::LibXML               qw( );
use XML::LibXML::XPathContext qw( );

my $xpc = XML::LibXML::XPathContext->new();
$xpc->registerNs(h => 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml');

my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
my $doc = $parser->parse_string($content);
my ($body_node) = $xpc->findnodes('/h:html/h:body', $doc)
   or die;

my $inner_body = join '', map $_->toString(), $body_node->childNodes();
print $inner_body;
```

Comment: How does the above method handle invalid html?

Comment: Again, you don't have HTML, you have XHTML/XML. It doesn't do anything if it isn't valid -- it doesn't even know if it's valid or not -- but it will die if it's not well-formed. You can use `$parser->recover(...)` to have it recover if possible.

Comment: (Example of *invalid* XHTML: A DIV element inside of a P element. Example of *malformed* XHTML: A missing closing tag or an unescaped `&`)

Comment: Thanks,, i'll give this try aswell .. also interested in getting  html::parse to work.