# How to redirect output from a Library's function in perl?

Tags: perl, redirect, output

I am trying to redirect the output from a library's function without changing the code in the library:

program.pl

```
use Lib::xxLib1xx;
...
xxLib1xx::Function1($Arg1);
```

xxLib1xx.pm

```
Function1{
    my $arg = shift;
    print "$arg\n";
}
```

How can I modify the code in program.pl so the when I call Function1, no output is seen? I cannot change the code in the Library itself.
If I did a system call, it would look like:

```
system("echo hello > nul");
```

Comment: Do you call Function1 explicitly?  If so, duplicate:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/16615269/132382 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered with help from shooper's response:

```
my $LOG;
open ($LOG, '>>', 'null');
select $LOG;
...
xxLib1xx::Function1($Arg1);
...
select STDOUT;
```

Answer (score 4):

And an answer without using CPAN modules can still be pretty compact:

```
my $stdout;
{
    local *STDOUT;
    open STDOUT, ">", \$stdout;
    xxLib1xx::Function1($Arg1);
}
print "Got '$stdout' from subroutine call!\n";
```

Answer (score 3):

Check out [Capture::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Capture::Tiny)

```
use Capture::Tiny qw[ capture ];
( $stdout, $stderr, @result) = capture { xxLib1xx::Function1($Arg1) };
```

Answer (score -1):

This is answered well at http://perltricks.com/article/45/2013/10/27/How-to-redirect-and-restore-STDOUT

Hope that helps.